# dotnet core 5 Webapi Send Json response to HTTPPOST

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] clsTicketInfo ticketInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
              {"id","72832"},
              {"name","John"}
             };
            var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            message.Content = new StringContent(jsonData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
             //      Request.CreateResponse()         
            return message;
           
        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         return   new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
            //HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created, ticketInfo);
    }
```

In this code, I want to send the Status ok and JSON data in my HTTP POST but it is not working. I am using dotnet core version 5.

Answer (score 0):

you need just this

```
public ActionResult Post([FromBody] clsTicketInfo ticketInfo)
{
  return Ok( new  { id =72832, name = "John" } );
}
```

http response with message will be automatically created by net mvc

Answer (score 0):

```html
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] clsTicketInfo ticketInfo)
    {
        try
        {
                
              var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                           {"id","72832"},
                           {"name","John"}
              
                         };
           var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            return ok(jsonData);
           
        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         return  Badrequest('error':ex.message)
        }
            
    }
```

IActionResult can send response to the front end when using ok,badrequest, notfound.

Comment: You should probably explain **why** this works and is the answer.